# Buildbot Installation Setup Error

Tags: python, continuous-integration, buildbot

So I tried to install buildbot onto a OS X machine, and was unable to install it through the setup.py file. When I tried to run: `sudo python setup.py build`, it returned this:

```
error in buildbot setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings
containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
```

I was wondering what I could do to fix this. I have buildbot installed on a machine running ubuntu right now, but cannot seem to install it on the OS X machine.

EDIT: here's a link to setup.py: https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/blob/master/master/setup.py

EDIT #2: Fixed the initial problem, but now when I run either `python setup.py build` or `python setup.py install` I keep getting an error:
`error: package directory buildbot/buildslave does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: To fix the problem initially, without having to do all of these steps, simply change the line specifying the version of sqlalchemy (under `setup_args['install_requires']` go to `sqlalchemy >= 0.6` and change it to `sqlalchemy == 0.7.10`)

Fixed the initial problem by just copy pasting their newest code from github (the link I posted above). However, it seems by doing just that, I included extra directories in the setup that weren't part of this version (i.e. buildbot.slave etc.). To fix that, I just copied the list labeled 'packages' from the original version of the setup.py, thus fixing  the problem.

```
'packages': ["buildbot",
          "buildbot.status", "buildbot.status.web","buildbot.status.web.hooks",
          "buildbot.changes",
          "buildbot.steps",
          "buildbot.steps.package",
          "buildbot.steps.package.deb",
          "buildbot.steps.package.rpm",
          "buildbot.steps.source",
          "buildbot.process",
          "buildbot.process.users",
          "buildbot.clients",
          "buildbot.monkeypatches",
          "buildbot.schedulers",
          "buildbot.scripts",
          "buildbot.db",
          "buildbot.db.migrate.versions",
          "buildbot.util",
          "buildbot.test",
          "buildbot.test.fake",
          "buildbot.test.unit",
          "buildbot.test.util",
          "buildbot.test.regressions",
          ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use easy_install?

```
sudo easy_install buildbot
```

Comment: with this version of buildbot(0.8.7) the version of sqlalchemy specified in setup.py causes an error in: "ImportError: cannot import name exceptions" when trying to create a master. On my ubuntu machine, this was solved by manually installing the files from the tar fles supplied online, however, this doesn't seem to be working on my Mac

Comment: Buildbot's tutorial specifically states ***root*** is not needed; see [First Run Tutorial](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html). however, running it without ***sudo*** results in *"error: Setup script exited with error: package directory 'buildbot/test' does not exist"* on CentOS.